# How to properly check the ACL using the authorization plugin in CakePHP 4?

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I am currently using CakePHP 4 with the following plugins installed:

- `cakephp/acl` CakePHP ACL plugin
- `cakephp/authorization` CakePHP authorization plugin

Before, we used the `AuthComponent` with the ACL plugin to check for authorization.

Now, the `AuthComponent` is deprecated and the alternative is to use the authorization plugin.

---

How do I use the ACL plugin together with the authorization plugin to check for authorization on each request?

Comment: These two plugins are not ment to work together, `cakephp/acl` is strictly ment for use with the deprecated auth component. If you want ACLs for `cakephp/authorization`, then you need to implement that yourself.

Comment: @OP were you able to achieve this? If yes, how? I'd be very interested in a solution as I have the same problem.